# sbpl_lattice_planner in ROS indigo

Tags: ros, sbpl-lattice-planner, sbpl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

As far as I know, [sbpl_lattice_planner](http://wiki.ros.org/sbpl_lattice_planner) has not been updated for ROS indigo. Are there any plans to update it for ROS indigo in the near future or should it be considered as deprecated?

Update: Both the versions of sbpl_lattice_planner mentioned in the answers are working but in both cases, I am having some problem in linking sbpl_lattice_planner with [sbpl](http://wiki.ros.org/sbpl). I have installed sbpl using `sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-sbpl`. Then, when I run `roslaunch sbpl_lattice_planner  move_base_sbpl_fake_localization_2.5cm.launch`, stage opens up with the map but then I get the following error:

```
[ INFO] [1430936937.523934202, 1.100000000]: Name is SBPLLatticePlanner
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'SBPL_Exception*'
[move_base_node-3] process has died [pid 32285, exit code -6, cmd /home/namankumar/catkin_ws/devel/lib/move_base/move_base __name:=move_base_node __log:=/home/namankumar/.ros/log/beecc1ea-f41d-11e4-ade8-d4bed9838fa3/move_base_node-3.log].
log file: /home/namankumar/.ros/log/beecc1ea-f41d-11e4-ade8-d4bed9838fa3/move_base_node-3*.log
```

Does anyone have any idea about why is this happening?

Thanks in advance.
Naman Kumar

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/208515/sbpl_lattice_planner-in-ros-indigo/) by [Naman](https://answers.ros.org/users/11186/naman/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1464 on 2015-05-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Here's another version that is confirmed to work on Indigo: https://github.com/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/sbpl_lattice_planner/commits/master

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2015-05-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Naman](https://answers.ros.org/users/11186/naman/) on 2015-05-06**:
Thanks @Stefan! Your version is also working but I am having some problem with linking sbpl_lattice_planner with [sbpl](http://wiki.ros.org/sbpl). I have updated my original question. Do you know why is that happening?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a fork of the sbpl_lattice_planner that works on Hydro, and will probably work on Indigo as well: https://github.com/trainman419/sbpl_lattice_planner

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2015-05-04

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Naman](https://answers.ros.org/users/11186/naman/) on 2015-05-06**:
Thanks @ahendrix! Your version is working but I am having some problem with linking sbpl_lattice_planner with [sbpl](http://wiki.ros.org/sbpl). I have updated my original question. Do you know why is that happening?

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2015-05-07**:
That's not a linking error; that's a runtime error. Your new problem is far enough from the original question that you should ask a new question.